# Store the sum of multiple columns together in another column

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have 5 columns `A,B,C,D,E` in a table in a certain Database.. Each is of type `INT` and I want them like this :

```
E = A+B+C+D
```

How should I do this in `phpmyadmin`? Is it possible? How?

Comment: `VIEW` will save the data on that field?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `VIEW` to achieve this:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT a, b, c, d, a+b+c+d as e FROM mytable;
```